# Restoring a `mongodump` backup from google cloud storage stream

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, mongodump, mongorestore

I want to restore a very large database dump directly from a google cloud storage object without having to download and save it to a local file, because of disk space constraint.

I have the database dumps produced by `mongodump` (with and without `--gzip`)

When I try to pipe the database dump data to mongorestore using the following command
(I referred to [Streaming transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming))

```
gsutil cp - gs://<bucket>/<object_path> | mongorestore --uri=<connection_uri> --archive
```

The process is stuck at the following output

```
Copying from <STDIN>...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/    0.0 B]
```

I'm not sure whether it's a `gsutil` or `mongorestore` issue

The file is a valid mongodump file, as I tried to download a small database dump and I could successfully restore it using `mongorestore --uri=<connection_uri> --archive=<local_file_path>`

gsutil version: 4.57

mongorestore version: 100.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash in your gsutil command is in the place of the source argument, not the destination, so it's trying copy from STDIN to the `gs://` path (which would overwrite your object!).

If you want to pipe the contents of your GCS object to another program, you can use `gsutil cp` and make the destination argument be the dash character, or more simply, just use `gsutil cat gs://...`